# php - how to calculate percentage with scale different from 0-100?

Tags: php, math

I want to check how percent is `$current` on the scale from `$minimum` to `$maximum`

```
$minimum = 0.5
$maximum = 5.5

$current = 2.5
```

How can I do that in PHP?

Comment: what about subtracting `minimum` from all values and then simply `current` divided by `maximum`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do that in PHP the same way you would do it in any other language or even if you write that calculation by hand.

Because minimum can be > 0 in your case, we subtract minimum from all values to make it easier in calculation. There's probably a faster way to do the maths behind that, however thats an algebra level that I cannot do

```php
public function getPercentageValue($maximum, $minimum, $value) {
    $tempMax = $maximum - $minimum;
    $tempValue = $value - $minimum;

    return $tempValue / $tempMax;
}
```

Now if we take your values into consideration when we call `getPercentageValue()`
we will get an answer of 0,4

```php
$result = getPercentageValue(5.5, 0.5, 2.5);
echo $result; // 0.4
```

If you want the value not as float but as 40 for 40% you would change the function so that it multiplies the answer by 100

```php
public function getPercentageValue($maximum, $minimum, $value) {
    $tempMax = $maximum - $minimum;
    $tempValue = $value - $minimum;

    return ($tempValue / $tempMax) * 100;
}
```